# Dynamic Commands and Parameters in Kubernetes Templates

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We would like to enrich our kubernetes environment with consul to have a portable layer for application/stage/peer configuration. These would be my steps, based on my current understanding:

- build / reuse a *docker image* to provide consul servers
- write a *controller* and a *service* configuration file for kubernetes
- configure a replication of three, based on details: [1](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/bootstrapping.html)
- **Magic**

The magic refers to the fact, that I would need to run a command like:

```
consul join <Node A Address> <Node B Address> <Node C Address>
```

on of the replicas that just started. I have two and half obstacles in my head:

- how will the command only be executed on one machine?
- how can I access the IP addresses of the peers?
- as a bonus question: How can I invoke another command, each time a new replica is started / moved?

My gut is telling me to write an own script which communicates with the internal *etcd* of *kubernetes* to see which nodes have been registered and picks up from there. Is this the right direction? Will  the *command* in the *controller* template be fired at the right time, i.e. **after** the *etcd* has been updated with the new pod/replica?

[Bootstrapping Consul Datacenters](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/bootstrapping.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is related to an open Github issue
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5017

Please follow along there for an answer.